# Using Laravel with microservices: Is it possible to use eloquent without a database?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, microservices, grpc

We're using a microservice architecture. There are 2 sets of data for the laravel service:

- The database that houses the admins.
- And all the other data that admins can access, which comes via GRPC
  calls to other services.

I want something like eloquent (maybe [API Resource](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-resources)?) for structuring data/relationships, but instead of making Database-queries to load data, it needs to make GRPC calls to other services. I was thinking of making a custom class that extends off of eloquent and overloading the protected functions that make calls to the database, but that sounds like a recipe for a bad time. If anybody has experience doing what I'm describing, what direction did you go? What worked? what didn't?

Comment: Maybe you can use or take inspiration from this project? https://github.com/colopl/laravel-spanner

Comment: And how do you plan on running cross-table queries with gRPC without the database?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov I wouldn't. A given RPC would return the data and relevant relationships. I could hydrate the data/relationships with this. If I need to load a relation, I'd have to handle that manually.

For example, I would have an RPC for loading a blog-post, which automatically includes the author. I could hydrate all this. But if I wanted to also get all the top blog-posts from the author, I'd have to use another gRPC call. I was hoping to use a custom lazy-loading function, (like `$author->posts()`) to make that gRPC call and get that info.

Comment: Then it should be something like [graphql](https://github.com/alexaandrov/laravel-graphql-client), with the ability to support your relations and include their data for the request. I don’t think it will be able to re-use complex Eloquent methods, but basic ones like “where” it should handle pretty easily. I’m not aware of any libraries that support this kind of functionality, unfortunately.

Comment: Rearchitecting is not an option. all other microservices are written in gRPC. graphQL is off the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I ended up not using eloquent at all. I continued using the protoc set up as [the documentation explains](https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/php/#protoc). But I used Route-binding to enable type-hinting in controllers:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use OurNamespace\GrpcClient;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use OurNamespace\Customer;
use OurNamespace\CustomerIdInput;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * This namespace is applied to your controller routes.
     *
     * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //

        parent::boot();
        Route::bind('customer', function ($customerId) {
            $grpcClient = app(GrpcClient::class);
            $customerIdInput = new CustomerIdInput();
            $customerIdInput->setCustomerId($customerId);
            list($customer, $status) = $grpcClient->GetCustomerDetails($customerIdInput)->wait();
            if ($status->code != 0) {
                error_log('ERROR - ' . print_r($status, 1));
                return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['There was an error retrieving that customer', $status->details]);
            }
            return $customer;
        });
```

The `GrpcClient` is coming from the AppServiceProvider. This way if we want to make a query we don't have to manually instantiate it.

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use OurNamespace\GrpcClient;
use Grpc\ChannelCredentials;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('OurNamespace\GrpcClient', function ($app) {
            return new GrpcClient(env('GRPC_HOST'), [
                'credentials' => ChannelCredentials::createInsecure(),
            ]);
        });
```